# can i overload a method with another one that takes the same parameters but has a different return type?

Tags: java, operator-overloading

For example can i have something like this:

```
public static void SAMENAME (sameparameter n) 
{
    some code ;
} 

public static String SAMENAME (sameparameter n) 
{
    similar code; 
    return someString ; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't allowed.

The method signature in Java is considered to be the method name and parameter list.  The return type is not part of the method signature.

> **Definition:** Two of the components of a
>   method declaration comprise the method
>   signature—the method's name and the
>   parameter types.

Source: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 3):

This isn't allowed. For the compiler it is possible that several fit. For instance:

```
SAMENAME(n);
```

Could return a String or be void, both are valid.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest illustration why you can't. Imagine you implement:

```
String overloadedMethod();
int overloadedMethod();
```

and now I call

```
overloadedMethod();
```

so, which one gets called ? Since the return type isn't mandated, you can't determine which method to call.

Comment: Easy.  In this theoretical language it would be whatever the LHS is.

Comment: There is no LHS. Note the 'java' tag on the question.

Comment: you could have the compiler force a LHS, but then in java your language is weekly typed, what if you have the LHS is char, and you have return short and long, which one do you match? This type of thing could only work in unambiguous way (ie: not having programmer learn arbitrary matching return/LHS matching rules) if it was a strongly typed language and + enforced never ignoring return values

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to overload a method on the return type. Have a read of the "Overloading Methods" section on the [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

As it states,

> The compiler does not consider return
>   type when differentiating methods, so
>   you cannot declare two methods with
>   the same signature even if they have a
>   different return type.

Answer (score 1):

No, because when the program came across the function call SameName(param n) it would not know which to use.

Answer (score 0):

no u cant do that.
coz somtimes in java, methods are called ignoring the return value which is known as "method calling for its side-effects."

consider this:

```
void x(){}
int x(){}

x();//method call   --allowed in java
```

how can java determine which `x()` is called.
so overloading based on return types is not allowed in java.